# UISearchBar Corner Radius

Tags: ios, swift, search, uisearchbar

I'm working on a project where I want searchbar with cirular corner radius. I make my custom searchbar class and inherit super UISearchBar class and apply this kind of code inside awakeFromNib.

```
class SearchBar: UISearchBar{

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
        self.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        if let textField = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField{
            textField.borderStyle = .none
            textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
    }
}
```

when I run app, iPad display my desired design like this
[image]

but when I run application on mobile it disturbed it's corner.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of awake from Nib add this frame related code in layout subviews

```
class SearchBar: UISearchBar{

        override func layoutSubviews() {
         //    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 2
           // better to use 
             self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.midX
        }
        override func awakeFromNib() {
           
            self.backgroundImage = UIImage()
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.tintColor = UIColor.white
            self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            if let textField = self.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField{
                textField.borderStyle = .none
                textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it disturb textfield design that is inside uisearchbar

Comment: how to post screen shot at comment

Comment: you can send it via wetransfeer.com